# Get backgroundColor and show in looped elements

Tags: javascript, for-loop, background-color

I have a bunch of elements all with class `.paletteSq` and all with different unique background colors.

I'm using a loop to go through each one and display the background color value, the hex code, within a span:

```
var i, len;
var tiles = document.querySelectorAll(".paletteSq");
function displayColor(){
    for(i = 0, len = tiles.length; i < len; i++){
        function rgbToHex(color)
        {
            if(color.charAt(0)=='r')
            {
                color=color.replace('rgb(','').replace(')','').split(',');
                var r=parseInt(color[0], 10).toString(16);
                var g=parseInt(color[1], 10).toString(16);
                var b=parseInt(color[2], 10).toString(16);
                r=r.length==1?'0'+r:r; g=g.length==1?'0'+g:g; b=b.length==1?'0'+b:b;
                var colHex='#'+r+g+b;
                return colHex;
            }
        }
        var color = tiles[i].style.backgroundColor;

        tiles[i].innerHTML = '<span class="hex">' +rgbToHex(color)+ '</span>';
    }
}
displayColor(tiles);
```

It's not working though. No console errors. I only get `undefined` displayed in the span beside each element instead of the hex color code.

Can anyone see what's going wrong?

Comment: function displayColor(tiles){} //since your passing a parameter as you call the function, though you already declared it as a global var.

Comment: If the colors are not rgb you will get undefined since you exit if(color.charAt.. =="r") will fail.

Comment: @jhek Ah yes. I removed `tiles` inside of `displayColor()` but still get undefined.

Comment: @dmoz anyway could you include your html codes and other js codes?

Comment: @jhek this is the only js on the page. I put everything in a codepen here: https://codepen.io/dmoz/pen/pdgVvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var color = window.getComputedStyle(tiles[i]).backgroundColor;
```

`el.style.backgroundColor` only returns the value you set on the element's actual style attribute, if any. To get the *actual* stylings use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)